# Add timepicker to system config

Tags: magento-1

I want to add time (hh:mm:ss) picker to admin system config using `system.xml` file. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely. You need to follow just a few steps to add date time picker in the configuration. I am assuming that you have created a custom module.

> Create/open **`system.xml`** file under **app/code/[codepool]/[NameSpace]/[Module]/etc** folder. In this file, you should have a structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
   ....
       <fields>
       ...
          <run translate="label">
           <label>Date</label>
           <frontend_type>text</frontend_type> <!-- Use text instead of "myDateSelection" -->
           <frontend_model>[module]/adminhtml_system_config_date</frontend_model> <!-- Call a module specific renderer model -->
           <sort_order>20</sort_order>
           <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
           <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
           <validate>required-entry</validate> <!-- Optional -->
           <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
          </run>
       </fields>
   ...
   </config>
```

> Now create a new file **`Date.php`** under **app/code/[codepool]/[NameSpace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config** folder and paste below code:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date;
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

        $data = array(
            'name'      => $element->getName(),
            'html_id'   => $element->getId(),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        );
        $date->setData($data);
        $date->setValue($element->getValue(), $format);
        $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));
        $date->setClass($element->getFieldConfig()->validate->asArray());
        $date->setForm($element->getForm());

        return $date->getElementHtml();
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you haven't defined block class yet, you first need to define block class in **app/code/[codepool]/[NameSpace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml** file.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

**Note:**

**[codepool]:** local/community

**[NameSpace]:** Your module's namespace

**[Module]:** Your module's name

**Update:** After question has been updated, for time picker, you need to add code like this in your system.xml file:

```
<time translate="label comment">
     <label>Time</label>
     <frontend_type>time</frontend_type>
     <sort_order>52</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</time>
```

Comment: not a time (hh:mm:ss) picker, but a date picker?

Comment: means you only need to show time picker? It should not be a date time picker??

Comment: Yeah, I want only the time (hh:mm:ss) picker. Sorry, didn't so clear on my initial question.

Comment: I have added details to add time picker in my answer. Please check my answer now.

Comment: You need to add code mentioned in **Update** part only.

Comment: ! Thank you so much. It displays the time picker now! :)

Comment: @John, please post your question as a separate question since the current question is for Magento 1. Please post the URL here so that others can know there is some similar question for Magento 2.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I actually have solved my problem, no worries I did post one earlier i since have deleted as another question kind of covers M2 but it doesnt work, but anyway i've found a work around so all good